# Custom SearchView whole clickable in android

Tags: android, android-styles, searchview, android-search

I have a `SearchView` widget in my app, and I want to ask some questions about making it custom. First of all, you can start search only by clicking on search icon, is there any way to make whole `SearchView` clickable?
Also, is there a way to make `SearchView` appear something like this when it is clicked?

[image: a busy cat]

It is now in this state:

[image: a busy cat]

Here is my code:

```
citySearch = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.city_search_bar);
citySearch.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_background);
citySearch.setOnSearchClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        citySearch.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        //citySearch.setIconified(true);
    }

});
citySearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

        ((Filterable) cityListView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(text);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

        return false;
    }

});

try
{
    Field searchField = SearchView.class.getDeclaredField("mSearchButton");
    searchField.setAccessible(true);
    ImageView searchBtn = (ImageView)searchField.get(citySearch);
    searchBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_icon);
    searchBtn.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.search_background);
}
catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
{
    Log.e("SEARCHSTYLEERROR",e.getMessage(),e);
}
catch (IllegalAccessException e)
{
    Log.e("SEARCHSTYLEERROR",e.getMessage(),e);
}
```

Comment: Ok, the first issue was solved using citySearch-s setOnClickListener.

Comment: You should answer this question with your comment...it solved my issue

Comment: @AnhaytAnanun  Have you solved these issues now? If so whats the solution? Can you pls share the solution... It might helps us too

Comment: @AnhaytAnanun check mark the answer. It is correct.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

By default the SearchView is 'iconified', which is displayed as a magnifying glass icon and only if the user clicks on the icon, then the edit field expands.

To enable the user to click anywhere on the SearchView and expand the input field. We just need to add a click listener and call setIconified(false) when the user clicks.

```
searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchView.setIconified(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

By default the SearchView is 'iconified'.
So you should use this code in java:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }
});
```

or use this in xml:

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />
```

this 2 ways is correct, but different in icons display.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way to do it by setting `onActionViewExpanded()`.

```
searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To allow writing when clicking in the whole component, I'd recommend you declaring `iconifiedByDefault="false"` on the xml.

```
<SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"/>
```

Comment: This is answer I was looking for. I just had to add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to layout to get rid of initial focus on Searchview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this anywhere in the code: `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);`

From Android SDK:

> When the SearchView is used in an ActionBar as an action view for a
> collapsible menu item, it needs to be set to iconified by default
> using setIconifiedByDefault(true). This is the default, so nothing
> needs to be done.
>
> If you want the search field to always be visible, then call
> setIconifiedByDefault(false).