# Android SearchView icon as search button

Tags: android, searchview

I Have SearchView that works well by inputting ENTER in soft keyboard, I want that search icon shown in search input also work as search button, something like this image: (it is not about styling just making Magnifier icon clickable)

[image: search box with clickable Magnifier icon]

is it possible?

Comment: Check here-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455723/android-make-whole-search-bar-clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I could solve this by getting access to default mag icon in search view by `R.id.search_mag_icon` and setting OnClickListener on it. it is not clean code but at least it work for me.

search activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.simple_list);
    final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    ImageView magImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_mag_icon);
    magImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.search);
    magImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentSelected = new Intent(SearchActivity2.this, SearchActivity2.class);
            intentSelected.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
            CharSequence query = searchView.getQuery();
            intentSelected.setData(Uri.parse( query.toString() ));
            intentSelected.putExtra("QUERY", query.toString());
            startActivity(intentSelected);
            hideKeyboard(SearchActivity2.this);
            finish();
        }
    });
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        String button_query = intent.getStringExtra("QUERY");
        if(query==null && button_query!=null)
            query = button_query;
        if(query!=null) {
            searchView.setQuery(query, false);
            headers = db.doSearch(query);
            dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
            dataModels = setListItems(headers);
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(dataModels, getApplicationContext());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.iv_noresult));
        }
    }
```